# Center images inside 2 columns of a section

Tags: javascript, html, css

Code is right now:

HTML:

```
            <section class="sponsorSection">
                <div class="sponsorImageRow">
                    <div class="sponsorImageColumn">
                        <img src="img/kvadrat_logo.png" class="sponsorpicture1"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sponsorImageColumn">
                        <img src="img/small_vertical_logo.png" class="sponsorpicture2"/><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sponsorImageRow">
                    <div class="sponsorImageColumn">
                        <img src="img/long_vertical_logo.png" class="sponsorpicture1"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="sponsorImageColumn">
                        <img src="img/logo4.png" class="sponsorpicture2"/><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="sponsorImageRow">
                    <div class="sponsorImageColumn">
                        <img src="img/logo5.jpg" class="sponsorpicture1"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
```

CSS:

```
.sponsorSection{
    width: 480px;
    margin-top:30px;
    border:2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.sponsorImageRow{
    height: 50px;
}
.sponsorImageColumn{
    width : 50% ;
    display: inline;
}
.sponsorpicture1{
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 95%;
    height : auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.sponsorpicture2{
    padding: 10px;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 95%;
    height : auto;

    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Though it does not look correct:

[image]

Comment: if you catch yourself using `div`s to mimic the functionality of a `table` then perhaps just using the table is the better option. :) Especially when you are using tabular data. I'm not 100% sure that what you are making is actually tabular data but the fact that you use the words "row" and "column" give me the idea that it is.

Comment: Please explain your downvotes guys.

Comment: I didn't downvote but I would guess that you received downvotes for the fact that your question doesn't contain an actual concretely formulated question ending with a question mark. You just state several things not asking anything specific.

Comment: Thanks :) Though I thought title made it quite obvious what I was going for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, if I understood your requested positioning correctly, but if I look at your code, you want your image to be horizontal centered? Since image is an inline element per default the margin:0 auto will not be considered. Try something like this:

```
/* keep it as a block element, not inline */
.sponsorImageColumn {
    width : 50% ;
    float:left;
    display: block;
}
/* and image also as a block element */
.sponsorSection img {
    display:block;
}
```

I put together a small [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axelmichel/thtbf/) to demonstrate. 
For more complex positioning you could have a look at the css-syntax display: table, table-row and so on, to emulate a classic table with other html elements.

Answer (score 0):

Make the following change to your CSS -

```
.sponsorImageColumn{
    width : 50% ;
    float : left; /*remove display property and use float as you want to set the width*/
}
```

hope this solves your query